# Regex, JS: Match text to end of line after specific word without including word in match

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to parse a document for a Node.js application. The regex I have created matches everything in a line after a specific word. However, I cannot find out how to exclude the specific word from the match. This is problematic because the specific word can have a variable amount of spaces between itself meaning I can't use a look behind to exclude the word. How can I exclude this word from my match?

https://regex101.com/r/kk7Lxe/2

Comment: I’m trying to understand the problem.

Given your example at regex101, what is the output you expect, or what’s the data you want to extract?

Comment: `{{l|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}`. I don't want to include the `|links = ` part in my match because there is a variable number of spaces between `links` and `=` depending on the place in the document which makes it hard to replace later.

Comment: Always include every piece of information relevant to your question in your question (not only in external links). You're probably looking for [`\|links *= *(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/kk7Lxe/3) - result in capture group 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regular Expression to match only `links` is

```
/^\s*\|links\s*?=\s*(.*)$/m
```

This will capture the value of links into capture group 1, which you can reference as `match[1]`. In JavaScript, this looks like this:

```js
const str = `
{{Song box 2
  |color     = black; color:#D7DA5F
  |image     = Kokoropv.jpg
  |title     = &quot;'''ココロ'''&quot;
* Romaji: Kokoro
* Official English: Heart
  |date      = March 2, 2008
  |views     = {{v|nn|2,738,496}}
  |singers   = [[Kagamine Rin]] act1
  |producers = [[Toraboruta-P]] (music, lyrics, illustration)
  |links     = {{l|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}
  |links = {{l|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}
}}
`
const match = str.match(/^\s*\|links\s*?=\s*(.*)$/m)
const links = match && match[1]
console.log(links)
```

### Advanced Solution

Personally I'd do a more generic solution that parses this list into an object and lets you easily reference all keys and values as needed:

```js
const getKeywordValuePairs = str => {
    const pattern = /^\s*\|(.*?)\s*?=\s*(.*)$/gm
    const result = {}
    let match
    while(match = pattern.exec(str)) {
      const [unused, key, value] = match
      result[key] = value
    }
    return result
}

const result = getKeywordValuePairs(`
{{Song box 2
  |color     = black; color:#D7DA5F
  |image     = Kokoropv.jpg
  |title     = &quot;'''ココロ'''&quot;
* Romaji: Kokoro
* Official English: Heart
  |date      = March 2, 2008
  |views     = {{v|nn|2,738,496}}
  |singers   = [[Kagamine Rin]] act1
  |producers = [[Toraboruta-P]] (music, lyrics, illustration)
  |links     = {{l|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}
  |links = {{l|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}
}}
`)

console.log(result)
console.log(result.links)
```

Comment: Valid point, @kemicofa. Given that both entries are the same except for different spacing, I am assuming that it’s actually just one line, and the other one is there for OP’s testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where you match each row you want and then you remove the part you don't need with String#match and String#replace ( also Array#map to transform each row that you previously matched)

I had originally attempted to use `reg.exec(data)` but that only matches the **first** solution **you want**

```js
const data = `{{Song box 2
  |color     = black; color:#D7DA5F
  |image     = Kokoropv.jpg
  |title     = &quot;'''ココロ'''&quot;
* Romaji: Kokoro
* Official English: Heart
  |date      = March 2, 2008
  |views     = {{v|nn|2,738,496}}
  |singers   = [[Kagamine Rin]] act1
  |producers = [[Toraboruta-P]] (music, lyrics, illustration)
  |links     = {{aaal|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}
  |links = {{l|nn|sm2500648}} {{l|mz|266689|defunct}}
}}`;

const reg = /\|links\s*=\s*[^\n]+/g

// destructuring same as
// reg.exec(data)[1]
const res = (data
   .match(reg)||[])
   .map(row=>row.replace(/\|links\s*=\s*/g, ""));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: That’s also a working solution. I see two opportunities for improvement: `match` can return null, so chaining `map` can fail. You can work around this by doing `.match(pattern) || []` to chain further methods. I also recommend using a capture group, which the lets you do `reg[1]` instead of replacing. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756091/199263

Comment: @AndreasPizsa `match` will only return one result. In the OPs post there are atleast two matches (reason why I used `exec`). It's true that `exec` can return null, updted.

Comment: I see what you mean now. `exec` needs to be called repeatedly for each match until it returns `null`.